# SQLLite wrapper for cocos2d-js in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-js

There exists a wrapper class in java `Cocos2dxLocalStorage` which helps in reading the files written by cocos2d-js in javascript. Does there exist some wrapper for objective c as well which can be used to read the sqllite database.

I can use [JMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) just wanted to know if there is something which cocos provides by itself.

Comment: You don't need a wrapper; Objective-C code can call C code, which is the language sqlite is implemented in.

Comment: Thanks torjanfoe for the reply. :) I am a newbie with objc and c++. Can you please more detailed description.. or else point me to some link which explains how this can be done..

Comment: The main [sqlite site](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like we dont need any third party wrapper for sqlite in obj-c. Obj-c has sqlite as a header library already built in. I referred to [SQLite Tutorial for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app) to get the idea about how to use it.

Comment: You can have a look at https://gist.github.com/siddhanth/01d78ee7464a156b55df for more reference